# How to track changes of two non-similar dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two dataframes :

```
  col1  col2
a  foo   NaN
b  qux   2.0
c  bar   NaN
d  baz   4.0
```

---

```
  col1  col2
a  foo   NaN
c  NaN   3.0
d  baz   5.0
e  xxx   6.0
```

My expected output is a python dictionnary exactly like below :

```
out_dict = {
    "b": "deleted", #because b disappeared in df2
    "c": {"col1": None, "col2": 3}, #because whole row of c was updated in df2
    "d": {"col2": 5}, #because only col2 of d was updated in df2
    "e": {"col1": "xxx", "col2": 6} #because e was added in df2
}
```

PS : Both dataframes will always have the same header but could potentially describe different number of rows.

Here is the dataframes used :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'qux', 'c': 'bar', 'd': 'baz'},
 'col2': {'a': np.nan, 'b': 2.0, 'c': np.nan, 'd': 4.0}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {'a': 'foo', 'c': np.nan, 'd': 'baz', 'e': 'xxx'},
 'col2': {'a': np.nan, 'c': 3.0, 'd': 5.0, 'e': 6.0}})
```

I tried using `df1.compare(df2)` but I got an error :

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled (both index and columns) DataFrame objects

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys ;)

Comment: your expected output doesn't have 'a' included? Is this an expectation or a mistake?

Comment: That was a mistake, I'm sorry guys. I just updated my question.

Comment: Your output is invalid python, you likely want to use dictionaries, not lists ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask the common values, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)+[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in a dictionary comprehension:

```
out = (  {k: "deleted" for k in df1.index.difference(df2.index)}
       | {k: g.droplevel(0).to_dict() for k, g in
          df2.where(df1.ne(df2)).stack().groupby(level=0)}
      )
```

Output:

```
{'b': 'deleted',
 'c': {'col2': 3.0},
 'd': {'col2': 5.0},
 'e': {'col1': 'xxx', 'col2': 6.0}}
```

##### keeping None

```
out = (  {k: "deleted" for k in df1.index.difference(df2.index)}
       | {k: {k2: v2 for k2, v2 in zip(g.droplevel(0).index, g)
             if v2 is None or pd.notna(v2)} for k, g in
          df2.mask(df1.notna()&df2.isna(), None)
             .where(df1.ne(df2)).dropna(how='all')
             .stack(dropna=False).groupby(level=0)}
      )
```

Output:

```
{'b': 'deleted',
 'c': {'col1': None, 'col2': 3.0},
 'd': {'col2': 5.0},
 'e': {'col1': 'xxx', 'col2': 6.0}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. There is only a small issue, for example when a cell got updated to None in `df2`, it is not visible in your `out`. For `c` we need to have `"c": {"col1": None, "col2": 3}`. Do you think we can fix that, please ?

Comment: @Rendezvous yes we can with a bit extra work ;)

Comment: I'm so impressed, thank you so much.

Comment: The tricky part is to discriminate None/NaN in the comparison ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you will need to allign your DataFrames:

`df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, fill_value=np.nan)`

2. Compare your Dataframes:

`comp = df1.compare(df2)`

3. Process the comparison

```
res = {}
for idx in set(df1.index).union(df2.index):
    if idx not in df2.index:
        res[idx] = "deleted"
    elif idx not in df1.index:
        res[idx] = {col: df2.loc[idx, col] for col in df2.columns}
    elif idx in comp.index:
        diff = comp.loc[idx]
        res[idx] = {col: df2.loc[idx, col] for col in diff.index.get_level_values(0)}
```

Here is entire code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'qux', 'c': 'bar', 'd': 'baz'},
 'col2': {'a': np.nan, 'b': 2.0, 'c': np.nan, 'd': 4.0}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {'a': 'foo', 'c': np.nan, 'd': 'baz', 'e': 'xxx'},
 'col2': {'a': np.nan, 'c': 3.0, 'd': 5.0, 'e': 6.0}})

# Step 1
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, fill_value=np.nan)

# Step 2
comp = df1.compare(df2)

# Step 3
res = {}
for idx in set(df1.index).union(df2.index):
    if idx not in df2.index:
        res[idx] = "deleted"
    elif idx not in df1.index:
        res[idx] = {col: df2.loc[idx, col] for col in df2.columns}
    elif idx in comp.index:
        diff = comp.loc[idx]
        res[idx] = {col: df2.loc[idx, col] for col in diff.index.get_level_values(0)}

print(res)
```

Comment: Sorry but is this an AI generated answer ? This does not help, it throws a whole page of errors..

Comment: i corrected the problems